# Make bar rounded echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts, baidu, ngecharts

Is there a way to make bar **rounded** on top in echarts? For ex in [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-simple)

I was able to found option **roundCap** for **polar** but unable to find anything for **simple bar** chart

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you want to set 'border-radius'?

```
var option = {
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'value'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
            type: 'bar',
            itemStyle: {
                emphasis: {
                    barBorderRadius: [50, 50]
                },
                normal: {
                    barBorderRadius: [50, 50, 0 ,0 ]
                }
            }
        }]
    };
```

Comment: It solved my one issue. But got another can you look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800234/overlapping-bar-chart-apache-echarts-baidu?

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya That's answered

Answer (score 0):

```
options = {
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            data: ['June ’22', 'July ’22',]
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'value'
        },
        series: [
            {
                data: [
                    
                    {
                        value: 140,
                        itemStyle: {
                            color: '#80CBC4',
                            barBorderRadius: 5,
                        },
                      
                    },  {
                        value: 250,
                        itemStyle: {
                            color: '#CE93D8',
                            barBorderRadius: 5,
                        }
                    }
],
                type: 'bar',
                barWidth: '40%'
            }
        ]
    };
```