# Overlapping bar chart apache echarts baidu

Tags: javascript, echarts, baidu, ngecharts

I want to create bar chart with multiple series **overlapping** each other.

Stack bar chart places bar on top of another bar.

I want all bar to **start** from the **bottom** like below example.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this with [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-simple) ?

Comment: Is this something you are looking for - https://ibb.co/kMpYQnq

Comment: @gautam Yes. Similar to that. It's just all bar should start from bottom. Not on top of another.

Comment: You can find the example here: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack

Comment: @Raymond It puts bar on top of bar. For ex one bar is of value 20 & another is 30 then on chart final bar should be 30 not 20+30=50. Current example provides a way to put one bar on top of another not overlappin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=bar-label-rotation)

added

```
series: [
    {
        name: 'Forest',
        type: 'bar',
        barGap: '-100%',  // this changed
        barCategoryGap: '80%', // this changed
        label: labelOption,
        data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390]
    },
    {
        name: 'Steppe',
        type: 'bar',
        label: labelOption,
        data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290]
    },
    {
        name: 'Desert',
        type: 'bar',
        label: labelOption,
        data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190]
    },
    {
        name: 'Wetland',
        type: 'bar',
        label: labelOption,
        data: [98, 77, 101, 99, 40]
    }
]
```

Comment: how to overlap only two bars instead all bars?